# AmCharts CategoryAxis AutoWrap?

Tags: word-wrap, amcharts

I have charts being built successfully by AmCharts. Now I would like to use CategoryAxis AutoWrap. I have added it to my AmChart call like so:

```
"categoryAxis": { 
   "gridThickness": 0, 
   "gridPosition": "start", 
   "autoWrap": true    
 },
```

...however, that doesn't seem to be enough yet, as the labels aren't wrapping. Note: the labels aren't rotated and they are horizontal.

What else do I need to do in order to get the text to wrap?

Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Answer (score 0):

Per AmCharts tech support, "autoWrap" does not currently wrap text the way I need it to. (I'm not sure yet exactly what the function of "autowrap" is.)

However, you can insert line breaks into text with "\n". That was all I needed in order to resolve this.